# Publishing and debugging Microsoft Bot Service

Tags: botframework

I have developed a bot that works perfectly on my local machine and accessible through all channels via ngrok.

However, the Bot doesn’t work on its deployed Azure url which is https://mybot.azurewebsites.com/api/messages A test with the webchat or bot emulator returns an error 500 without further information on exact cause of the issue. How would I debug so that I can find out more information on what's causing the breakdown?

Comment: Maybe add a capture of the emulator with the settings pane opened, and the log visible

Comment: The SDK, and SDK version would also be helpful. If you're able to, the code for your bot would also help.

Comment: You can enable [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) for your bot application hosting on Azure, which could help trace and check the requests and responses.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I checked the log stream which then helped to inform on what to do. I had to change Visual Studio setting to delete files each time I deployed the application.

Comment: `change Visual Studio setting to delete files each time I deployed the application` Hi @MasindeMuliro, do you mean that the bot works if you checked "Remove additional files at destination" option while deploying it to Azure?

Comment: @MasindeMuliro check this, might helpful for you to debug your BOT to get the real issues. [Debug Azure BOT from Visual Studio](https://hasanmahmood.com/2019/03/05/debugbotservicelocally/)